# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Code] IN('

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access, sql-update

I am getting an error while updating the data, the error says: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Code] IN('."

Here is the code where i am getting an error at:

```
OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Here is the full code of the function that the error is appear:

```
private void UpdateQuantity()
        {
            int index = 0;

            string command = "UPDATE [Seranne] SET [Quantity] ='" + newVal + "' WHERE [Code] IN(";

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

            conn.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Quantity", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);

            OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dReader.Read())
            {
                if (textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value != 0 && textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value >= Convert.ToDecimal(dReader["Quantity"].ToString()))
                {
                    newVal = Convert.ToDecimal(dReader["Quantity"].ToString()) - textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value;
                }

                System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
                sound.Play();
                MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully", "Success");

                index += 1;
            }

            conn.Close();
            dReader.Close();
        }
```

Here is the previous code where the query expression "Code IN":

```
string query = "SELECT [Quantity], [Description], [Price] FROM [Seranne] WHERE [Code] IN (";

                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

                conn.Open();

                if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0].Text, out codeValue))
                {
                    query = query + codeValue.ToString();
                }

                for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++)
                {
                    if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[i].Text, out codeValue))
                    {
                        query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
                    }
                }

                query = query + ")";

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

                cmd.Parameters.Add("Code", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("Quantity", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);

                OleDbDataReader dReader;

                dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dReader.Read())
                {
                    if (textBoxCodeContainer[index].TextLength != 0)
                    {
                        this.textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Maximum = Convert.ToDecimal(dReader["Quantity"].ToString());
                        this.textBoxDescContainer[index].Text = dReader["Description"].ToString();
                        this.textBoxSubTotalContainer[index].Text = dReader["Price"].ToString();
                    }

                    index += 1;
                }

                conn.Close();
                dReader.Close();
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: your query isn't complete string command = "UPDATE [Seranne] SET [Quantity] ='" + newVal + "' WHERE [Code] IN(";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, just keep your code and change this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
   if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[i].Text, out codeValue))
   {
      query = query + codeValue + ",";
   }
}
query = query.TrimEnd(',') + ")";
```

Comment: i used your suggestion, but it gives me an error: `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression: [Code] IN ('')0`. And when i use `WHERE [Code] IN ('"`; and the `query = query + "')"`; it gives me an error: `data type mismatch`

Comment: @FuhansPujiSaputra why did you have the `0` after? Please see the code in my answer carefully.

Comment: i don't know also, that is same exactly like the error from program gives me

Comment: @FuhansPujiSaputra I didn't read your code carefully, see my update if it works now.

Comment: Perfect! It is working like a miracle! Thanks a bunch @King King

Comment: @FuhansPujiSaputra accepting a helpful answer is the best way to say thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

before proceed you better create integer list out of textBoxCodeContainer values, say it as integers

then

```
string command = "UPDATE [Seranne] SET [Quantity] =? WHERE [Code] IN(" + string.Join(", " , integers) +")";
```

Generate integer list as below

```
List<int> integers = new List<int>();
foreach (var tb in textBoxCodeContainer)
{
    int codeValue;
    if (int.TryParse(tb.Text, out codeValue))
    {
        integers.Add(codeValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of `create integer list out of textBoxCodeContainer values`? i am new at this thing. Thank you

Comment: Hai Damith, thanks for your code, it's works perfectly! Thanks a lot. But i change the code that you gave me, to this one (the Quantity): SET [Quantity]="+newVal+" and variable for the newVal: newVal = textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value - Convert.ToDecimal(dReader["Quantity"].ToString()); The value of quantity is still 100, once i run the program i change the value to 10 in the program and update it, it been successfully updated and the value of it in the database changed, but the value is 0 (supposed to be 90, because the code in newVal). The result will be 0, no matter what value i give